# Databricks is always auto starting

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I can't put Databricks to idle because something is auto starting it. I have no idea how to check it. Here are some of the details I found so far...

Event Log

```
STARTING
2020-12-28 13:07:42 PST
Started by b161878e-ff38-4fca-924a-b5c5ce4c3193.
```

Running Applications

```
Application ID
- app-20201228051029-0000   
Name
- Databricks Shell  
Cores
4   
Memory per Executor
- 7.1 GiB       
Resources Per Executor
-
Submitted Time
- 2020/12/28 05:10:29   
User
- root  
State
- RUNNING   
Duration
- 27 s
```

Tried killing this but got `Method Not Allowed`.

No running Jobs

No attached Notebooks

I have limited Databricks knowledge, and I don't know how to check who started it. Any help is very much appreciated.

Added event logs details.

Event during termination because of inactivity.

```json
{
  "reason": {
    "code": "INACTIVITY",
    "type": "SUCCESS",
    "parameters": {
      "inactivity_duration_min": "60"
    }
  }
}
```

After a few seconds, it's going to start again.

```json
{
  "user": "b161878e-ff38-4fca-924a-b5c5ce4c3193"
}
```

[image: dbricks-event-logs]

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot of the event logs and to get more information about an event, click its row in the log and then click the JSON tab for details.

Reference: https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/clusters-manage.html#view-cluster-logs

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT added your requests.

Comment: Could you please raise a support ticket with Microsoft?